# Error while performing OCR using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

I wanna to use pytesseract. This is my code.

```
import pytesseract 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 

PDF_file = 'file.pdf'
text = '' 
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500)
pageText = str(((pytesseract.image_to_string(pages[0]))))
```

and at result I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 409, in pdfinfo_from_path
>       proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>     File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
>       self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>     File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
>       hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\pdfparser\pdftest.py", line 13, in 
>       pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500)
>     File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 89, in convert_from_path
>       page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]
>     File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 430, in pdfinfo_from_path
>       raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError(
>   pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Comment: System can't find file.pdf. Is it in the same directory you are launching your script from?

Comment: is poppler installed and in path?

Comment: Yes there are in the same directory

Comment: but is poppler in path?

Comment: @NicolasGervais no, I add it and it work thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a lot of comments already pointed out, the error message

> PDFInfoNotInstalledError( pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Tells you precisely what went wrong: Poppler is not installed. Please refer to the [README](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image#windows) for help on that side.

You see, `pdf2image` is only a wrapper around the `pdftoppm` command-line utility. On Linux it is installed by default so you would not need to bother with it, but on Windows it is not.